# ModernWindow TitleLinks Command Binding

Tags: modern-ui

How can I bind a `TitleLinks` entry to an `ICommand`? Perhaps something like this:

```
<mui:ModernWindow.TitleLinks>
    <mui:Link x:Name="UpdateLink" DisplayName="Updates" Command="{Binding CmdUpdate}" />
</mui:ModernWindow.TitleLinks>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been stuck with a "logout" link. There is not a Command property, so I solved redirecting to a content page where Navigate event does what I need.

Comment: Good idea! Marking as answer.